# Run tests from Android Studio but terminal

Tags: android, intellij-idea, junit, android-studio, robolectric

I'm using [decard-gradle](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle) to run my junit tests in Android Studio.

It's all fine if you run tests from terminal, i.e. `./gradlew clean test`, but if you want to debug during your tests execution you need to run them from IDE (Android Studio in my case).

In order to debug you need to add a new Gradle configuration in your Run/Debug Configurations - `clean test` - and if you want the only one test class to execute then you create a JUnit configuration where you put 'launch another configuration' and specify gradle conf you created in prev step.

Sometimes I can see a list of tests within my test class with results, sometimes - not. I experimented a lot but didn't find a way how to make them always show. That's not really about debbuging only, this also applies to simple test run - sometimes you can see a list of tests, sometimes - not.

Configuration:
Android Studio 0.8.14
gradle-2.1
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i understood correct, then you like to run single tests in Android Studio. I can tell you different ways:

1. Use Intellij with Android Plugin, thats the way supported by deckard-gradle.
2. The robolectric-gradle-plugin "support" run tests in Android Studio it but need much manual effort also explained here at the last "obsolete" part https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template/wiki/Tests-in-Android-Studio---IntellJ
3. Switch robolectric support plugin https://github.com/novoda/gradle-android-test-plugin and here is a "deckard project" https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template/tree/novoda
4. Switch robolectric support plugin https://github.com/JCAndKSolutions/android-unit-test which his extra created Android Studio plugin. It contains a sample and you can also find a sample here https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template